# Ruby on rails without models - if data CRUD is performed by webservices API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have been pondering about developing a new application with rails (probably without models?). What I meant is; backend will be written in any other language and that will provide the RESTful APIs, which will be consumed by Rails app.

Since backend API will take care of all data CRUD actions and rails app will not have access to database directly. So there is no use of rails model in such architecture?

I can directly make curl call to APIs from controllers too, but I wish to keep my controller skinny while fat models.

Or other way, API curl calls can be made in the models and it can behave like data CRUD being done to the database in that model.

In any of above scenarios, I will not be able to get benefit of many rails features or gems (such as friendly_id) which works on active records/ORM.

I am really confused as which way I should go? And what is the best practice? What architecture you can suggest? I definitely wants to keep my backend completely decoupled and providing only RESTful apis only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html).

You'll end up with models, but most will only take up one line.

Say your api service has a url like: http://api.fart.com/products.json which spits out a list of products. In your rails app that will be consuming this data, create a `Product` model inheriting from `ActiveResource`. First, set your api url for activeresource.

```
class ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.fart.com"
end
```

Next, define a Product class.

```
class Product < ActiveResource::Base; end
```

Now, in your controllers, you can do:

```
Product.all
```

And it should hit "http://api.fart.com/products.json" and return the good stuff.

Obviously this is a quickly contrived example, but I have recently used it for a similar situation and it worked great.

///////////////

see [example applications](https://github.com/davidglivar/stack_rest_api) for basic concept.

///////////////

Per your questions and your pull requests on github I understand what you are trying to do now. `ActiveResource` does not come with a `where` method - however, it's `find` method has an options argument that supports a params hash.

Rails controller with query params

```
def index
  @products = Product.find :all, params: { country: "Brazil", price: 500 }
end
```

This will hit our Sinatra route at api.fart.com/products.json?country=Brazil&price=500

```
# Assume we are using ActiveRecord/DataMapper or the like
get "/products.json" do
  @products = Product.where country: params[:country], price: params[:price].to_i
  json products: @products
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly I was looking for. My only concern is using friendly_id for slug. Is there any way to have it in such implementation?

Comment: Also suppose I have a REST api url like GET http://api.fart.com/products/edible?minprice=200&maxprice=233434&type=organic&from=brazil  so in such case, how my product class will look like? Also in controller, how I will make call to such url?

Comment: @JVK, I'm creating a quick sample app for you now. I'll post to github in a little bit. In short, friendly_id appears to be solely for ActiveRecord, but can be duplicated easily.

Comment: @JVK see example applications link at the bottom.

Comment: I got the slug part. Thank you :) . But my original question is still un-answered. suppose I have a REST api url like GET http://api.fart.com/products/edible?minprice=200&maxprice=233434&type=organic&from=brazil so in such case, how my product class in rails (not in sinatra app) will look like? I also came to know, activeresource used to be the part of rails, but it has bene now removed from rails because of some issues. So is it advisable to keep using it?

Comment: Also here, https://github.com/davidglivar/stack_rest_api/blob/master/consumer/app/models/product.rb, don't you need to set, something like: self.site = "http://api.fart.com"

Comment: ActiveResource will make an educated guess when it comes to resourceful routes. so in your controller `Product.find(:all)` will automatically hit your api route api.fart.com/products.json, `Product.find(1)` will hit api.fart.com/products/1.json. So there is no need to define any extra methods in your rails product model to get those routes unless you do something unconventional. `self.site` is set in an initializer [here](https://github.com/davidglivar/stack_rest_api/blob/master/consumer/config/initializers/active_resource.rb), no need to set it for ever model unless it changes.

Comment: In rails 3.2.8, activeresource is still bundled in. Otherwise you can always just include it as a gem from [github](https://github.com/rails/activeresource). Does it have its problems? yes. Very limited compared to ActiveRecord, but I have not seen an 'out-of-the-box' alternative to it.

Comment: So you mean if a clint is trying to access following rest api http://api.fart.com/products/edible?minprice=200&maxprice=233434&type=organic&from=brazil then in controller `Product.find(:all)` will automagically call http://api.fart.com/products/edible?minprice=200&maxprice=233434&type=organic&from=brazil even I have not passed these params in Product.find(:all, ....all other parameters here) ?

Comment: Yup. Try booting up those two sample apps I built and test it out.

Comment: @JVK, ok, merged your pull requests. I'll put an update in the answer as to what you are trying to do.